# Updating Page After DELETE Request Using MongoDB, Node and Express

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm building a Node/Mongo/Express/Jquery application that's correctly processing a `DELETE` request but it does not refresh the page afterwards to update its contents.

I tried the answer posted for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750169/expressjs-res-redirect-after-delete-request), but after including

```
req.method = 'GET'
```

inside the `router.delete(url, callback)` code block I was not getting different results.

**CODE:**

```
router.delete('/formula-list/:id', function(req, res){
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('formulas');
  var id = req.params.id;
  var query = { "_id": id };
  collection.findOneAndDelete(query);
  req.method = 'GET';
  res.redirect('/formula-list');
});
```

Again, the 'DELETE' request works just fine using a jQuery AJAX call, but I want the page to update to reflect that an item has been deleted from the database.

I've also tried the following to no avail:

```
router.delete('/formula-list/:id', function(req, res){
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('formulas');
  var id = req.params.id;
  var query = { "_id": id };
  collection.findOneAndDelete(query);
  collection.find({}, {}, function(e, docs){
  res.render('formula-list', {
    formulas: docs,
    title: 'Your Formulas',
    description: `List of saved user formulas from the formula generator`,
    ID: 'formula-list',
    keywords: 'formula generator, health kismet, nutraceutical formula  builder'
    });
  });
});
```

The idea here is that once I delete the item from the database I I re-send the collection to the URL to be re-displayed.  I did this with and without adding `req.method = 'GET'` but this did not work either.

Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your front-end structure. If you are using single page application like Vue.js or React.js, what you can do is after ajax has been resolved, call a get query to fetch all the data from database again.

```
$ajax.delete('/formula-list/:id')
  .then(res => {
    $ajax.get('/formula-list')
     .then(res => {
       this.tableData = res.data
      })
   })
```

If you are doing SSR, maybe you can try `window.location.reload(true)` from front-end